# Repeated code in two js functions, how to eliminate and make code elegant

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so I have the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
    // variables for the different pulldown menu's
    var selectPotency = document.getElementById("select-potency");
    var selectEssence = document.getElementById("select-essence");
    var selectAspect = document.getElementById("select-aspect");


    // defualt values of runes
    document.getElementById('potencyRune').innerHTML = 'Jode';
    document.getElementById('essenceRune').innerHTML = 'Oko';
    document.getElementById('aspectRune').innerHTML = 'Ta';

    // start with white glyph text
    document.getElementById('glyph').style.color = "#FFF";
    document.getElementById('select-potency').style.color = 'inherit';
    document.getElementById('select-essence').style.color = 'inherit';
    document.getElementById('select-aspect').style.color = 'inherit';

    // lookup tables for runes and translations
    var PotencyTable1 = {...};
    var PotencyTable0 = {...};
    var EssenceTable = {...};
    var AspectTable = {...};

    // This function changes the potency rune from select-potency
    selectPotency.onchange=function getPotency() {
        var potency = this.value;
        var elem = document.getElementById('select-essence');
        var polarity = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;

        if (polarity == 0) {
            document.getElementById('potencyRune').innerHTML = PotencyTable0[potency]();
        }
        if (polarity == 1) {
            document.getElementById('potencyRune').innerHTML = PotencyTable1[potency]();
        }   
    }

    // This function changes the essence rune from select-essence
    selectEssence.onchange=function getEssence() {
        var essence  = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
        var polarity = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

        var elem = document.getElementById('select-potency');
        var potency = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;

        document.getElementById('essenceRune').innerHTML = EssenceTable[essence]();

        if (polarity == 0) {
            document.getElementById('potencyRune').innerHTML = PotencyTable0[potency]();
        }
        if (polarity == 1) {
            document.getElementById('potencyRune').innerHTML = PotencyTable1[potency]();
        }
    }

    // This function changes the color of the glyph name & aspect rune from select-aspect
    selectAspect.onchange=function getAspect() {
        var aspect = this.value;
        var colour = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-color');

        document.getElementById('glyph').style.color = colour;
        document.getElementById('aspectRune').innerHTML = AspectTable[aspect]();
    }
}
```

Now there's 3 different areas where I have code repeated because I don't know how else to do it:

1) the //default values of runes - each of the 3 different functions sets these values when the user makes their selection from the drop down, but I don't know how to make these functions run at page load to get the initial values of the drop down selects so I've done it this way to set the default values.

2) the //start with white glyph text - again, similar to #1, I don't know how to make the getAspect function run at page load to set the color white so i'm manually setting the text color white.

3) in functions getPotency and getEssence there are two if statements that are completely identical. they belong to the getPotency function but the getEssence function also changes them but I didn't know how to make a call to it so i'm repeating the code.

4) lastly, if you have any alterations to make my code more elegant/professional I would greatly appreciate it. I'm self taught and this is my first time dabbling with javascript.

Thank you very much in advance for all your feedback!

[Here's the website I've got soo far with the code](http://eso.dstealth.com/enchanting/)

Comment: Question very well drafted.will get back to you with answer soon

Comment: One way could be using jQuery in order to condense the code is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is the kind of question better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but since it is clear that you put some time and effort into your question I will provide an answer on this site anyways.

Here are a few pointers to help you understand how I went about refactoring your code:

- Have each `Table` store values as strings, instead of functions that return strings;
- Combine your `PotencyTable`s together using arrays of length 2, which has the side effect of removing the need to use an `if` statement when accessing runes based on polarity;
- Default `#glyph` color (`#fff`) and `color: inherit` on `#glyph >
  select`  would be better set by CSS instead of JavaScript;
- Change `innerHTML` to `textContent` when you're not inserting tags;
- Move each `<script>` just before the `</body>` tag to avoid the need to use `onload`;
- Use a different, nested data structure to store your `<select>`, rune, and table of lookup values all in one place (one each for `Potency`, `Essence`, and `Aspect`);
- `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value` can be shortened to `select.value`;
- Put your colors and polarities inside your nested data structure instead of embedded in HTML;
- Combine all event listeners into a single `update` function, and add them to each of your `select`s with a `forEach` loop; and
- Call `update()` once before the end of your script instead of setting the default runes manually.

When running the snippet below, be sure to click "Full Page" or else the content gets cut off.

---

### Refactored Code:

```css
#glyph > select {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="http://dstealth.com/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://eso.dstealth.com/style.css" />
  <title>ESODEX - Enchanting Glyph Calculator</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.85, minimum-scale=0.85">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="header" class="fog">
      <div id="table-cell">
        <div align="center">
          <span class="f30">Lethal's ESODEX</span><br/>
          <span class="f20 teal fog">&nbsp;&nbsp;Enchanting&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="smoketop">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="fogcontent" class="fogcontent">
        <div id="content" align="center">
          <br/>
          <span id="glyph">
   <select id="select-potency">
    <option value="trifling">LVL .1 - Trifling</option>
    <option value="inferior">LVL .5 - Inferior</option>
    <option value="petty">LVL 10 - Petty</option>
    <option value="slight">LVL 15 - Slight</option>
    <option value="minor">LVL 20 - Minor</option>
    <option value="lesser">LVL 25 - Lesser</option>
    <option value="moderate">LVL 30 - Moderate</option>
    <option value="average">LVL 35 - Average</option>
    <option value="strong">LVL 40 - Strong</option>
    <option value="major">LVL C10 - Major</option>
    <option value="greater">LVL C30 - Greater</option>
    <option value="grand">LVL C50 - Grand</option>
    <option value="splendid">LVL C70 - Splendid</option>
    <option value="monumental">LVL C100- Monumental</option>
   </select>
   &nbsp;Glyph of&nbsp;
   <select id="select-essence" name="essence-all">
    <option>Absorb Health</option>
    <option>Absorb Magicka</option>
    <option>Absorb Stamina</option>
    <option>Bashing</option>
    <option>Crushing</option>
    <option>Decrease Health</option>
    <option>Decrease Physical Harm</option>
    <option>Decrease Spell Harm</option>
    <option>Disease Resist</option>
    <option>Fire Resist</option>
    <option>Flame</option>
    <option>Foulness</option>
    <option>Frost</option>
    <option>Frost Resist</option>
    <option>Hardening</option>
    <option>Health</option>
    <option>Health Regen</option>
    <option>Increase Magical Harm</option>
    <option>Increase Physical Harm</option>
    <option>Magicka</option>
    <option>Magicka Regen</option>
    <option>Poison</option>
    <option>Poison Resist</option>
    <option>Potion Boost</option>
    <option>Potion Speed</option>
    <option>Rage</option>
    <option>Reduce Feat Cost</option>
    <option>Reduce Spell Cost</option>
    <option>Shielding</option>
    <option>Shock</option>
    <option>Shock Resist</option>
    <option>Stamina</option>
    <option>Stamina Regen</option>
    <option>Weakening</option>
   </select>
   &nbsp;
   <select id="select-aspect">
    <option style="color:#FFF;" value="base">Base</option>
    <option style="color:#2DC50E;" value="fine">Fine</option>
    <option style="color:#3A92FF;" value="superior">Superior</option>
    <option style="color:#A02EF7;" value="artifact">Artifact</option>
    <option style="color:#E5CB51;" value="legendary">Legendary</option>
   </select><br/>
  </span>
          <br/>
          <hr><br/><br/>
          <div id="runes" class="f15">
            <span id="potencyRune">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span id="essenceRune">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span id="aspectRune">&nbsp;</span>
          </div>
          <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="smokebot">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="footer" class="fog" align="center">
      <div id="table-cell">
        <div align="center">
          <span class="f10">Last Updated Mar. 26, 2017</span><br/><br/>
          <span id="align-left" class="f10">For ESO version: 2.7.10</span>
          <span id="align-right" class="f10">&copy; Copyright 2017</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Potency = {
      $select: document.getElementById("select-potency"),
      $rune: document.getElementById('potencyRune'),
      runes: {
        "trifling": ["Jode", "Jora"],
        "inferior": ["Notade", "Porade"],
        "petty": ["Ode", "Jera"],
        "slight": ["Tade", "Jejora"],
        "minor": ["Jayde", "Odra"],
        "lesser": ["Edode", "Pojora"],
        "moderate": ["Pojode", "Edora"],
        "average": ["Rekude", "Jaera"],
        "strong": ["Hade", "Pora"],
        "major": ["Idode", "Denara"],
        "greater": ["Pode", "Rera"],
        "grand": ["Kedeko", "Derado"],
        "splendid": ["Rede", "Recura"],
        "monumental": ["Kude", "Cura"]
      }
    }

    var Essence = {
      $select: document.getElementById("select-essence"),
      $rune: document.getElementById('essenceRune'),
      runes: {
        "Absorb Health": "Oko",
        "Absorb Magicka": "Makko",
        "Absorb Stamina": "Deni",
        "Bashing": "Jaedi / Kaderi",
        "Crushing": "Deteri",
        "Decrease Health": "Okoma",
        "Decrease Physical Harm": "Lire / Taderi",
        "Decrease Spell Harm": "Makderi",
        "Disease Resist": "Haoko",
        "Fire Resist": "Rakeipa",
        "Flame": "Rakeipa",
        "Foulness": "Haoko",
        "Frost": "Dekeipa",
        "Frost Resist": "Dekeipa",
        "Hardening": "Deteri",
        "Health": "Oko",
        "Health Regen": "Okoma",
        "Increase Magical Harm": "Makderi",
        "Increase Physical Harm": "Lire / Taderi",
        "Magicka": "Makko",
        "Magicka Regen": "Makkoma",
        "Poison": "Kuoko",
        "Poison Resist": "Kuoko",
        "Potion Boost": "Oru",
        "Potion Speed": "Oru",
        "Rage": "Okori",
        "Reduce Feat Cost": "Denima",
        "Reduce Spell Cost": "Makkoma",
        "Shielding": "Jaedi / Kaderi",
        "Shock": "Meip",
        "Shock Resist": "Meip",
        "Stamina": "Deni",
        "Stamina Regen": "Denima",
        "Weakening": "Okori"
      },
      polarities: {
        "Absorb Health": 0,
        "Absorb Magicka": 0,
        "Absorb Stamina": 0,
        "Bashing": 1,
        "Crushing": 0,
        "Decrease Health": 0,
        "Decrease Physical Harm": 0,
        "Decrease Spell Harm": 0,
        "Disease Resist": 0,
        "Fire Resist": 0,
        "Flame": 1,
        "Foulness": 1,
        "Frost": 1,
        "Frost Resist": 0,
        "Hardening": 1,
        "Health": 1,
        "Health Regen": 1,
        "Increase Magical Harm": 1,
        "Increase Physical Harm": 1,
        "Magicka": 1,
        "Magicka Regen": 1,
        "Poison": 1,
        "Poison Resist": 0,
        "Potion Boost": 1,
        "Potion Speed": 0,
        "Rage": 1,
        "Reduce Feat Cost": 0,
        "Reduce Spell Cost": 0,
        "Shielding": 0,
        "Shock": 1,
        "Shock Resist": 0,
        "Stamina": 1,
        "Stamina Regen": 1,
        "Weakening": 0
      }
    }

    var Aspect = {
      $select: document.getElementById("select-aspect"),
      $rune: document.getElementById('aspectRune'),
      runes: {
        "base": "Ta",
        "fine": "Jejota",
        "superior": "Denata",
        "artifact": "Rekuta",
        "legendary": "Kuta"
      },
      colors: {
        "base": "#FFF",
        "fine": "#2DC50E",
        "superior": "#3A92FF",
        "artifact": "#A02EF7",
        "legendary": "#E5CB51"
      }
    }

    var glyph = document.getElementById('glyph')

    function update() {
      var potency = Potency.$select.value
      var essence = Essence.$select.value
      var aspect = Aspect.$select.value

      var polarity = Essence.polarities[essence]
      var color = Aspect.colors[aspect]


      glyph.style.color = color

      Potency.$rune.textContent = Potency.runes[potency][polarity]
      Essence.$rune.textContent = Essence.runes[essence]
      Aspect.$rune.textContent = Aspect.runes[aspect]
    }

    [Potency, Essence, Aspect].forEach(function(E) {
      E.$select.addEventListener('change', update)
    })

    update()
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".fade").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      linkLocation = this.href;
      $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
      window.location = linkLocation;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you soo much! SOO MUCH to learn from this! A few questions: Why are the $select and $rune prefixed with $ but the runes tables not? How does a call A)  'Potency.$select' differ from a call B) 'Potency.runes' ?

Comment: Other question: How does the update() function know when to run? There's on onchange handler I can see anywhere so what keeps it running?

Comment: Glad to help. Let me address your questions. First, `$select` and `$rune` are only prefixed with `$` as a matter of style (so I can distinguish them as DOM elements); the program would run equally well if you replaced those names with just `select` and `rune` as long as you made all references consistent. `Potency.$select` and `Potency.runes` are the same kind of property call, but it just so happens that in JavaScript a property identifier can begin with the special characters `_` or `$` if you like.

Comment: The `update()` function knows when to run because I did add it as an event listener to each select, but using `E.$select.addEventListener('change', update)` (where `E` is `Potency`, `Essence`, and `Aspect` inside a `forEach` loop) instead of `E.$select.onchange = update`. `addEventListener` is the more common style nowadays because it lets you set more than one event listener per element per event.